# App invited email text includes html tags

Tags: google-play-services, google-app-invites

On my app description I've started using some basic html to format things better, mostly `<p>` tags, `<ul>` and things like that. The description looks ok on the Play Store but when a user sends an app invite the tags are visible in the text.

Any way to fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I tried `App invite` app [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/appinvites), and no issue of that.

Comment: What is the play store listing for that sample? does it have html inside the play store listing?